# Reaction between ammonia and dichloromethane

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, polymers

Could ammonia displace a chloride in dichloromethane to form a methylammonia? If so, given enough reagents and time, could this be used to make a 3D structure comprised of nitrogen bonded carbons, and carbons bonded to nitrogen and hidrogen?

Comment: You mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexamethylenetetramine ?

Comment: Kind of. I guess a exaustive alkylation could occur though, extending the structure.

Comment: I was not aware of that synthesis though. I guess if that stops there, the same would be observed in my experiment. Why does it stop there though? Why doesn't a nitrogen attack another aldehyde?

Comment: There apparently exists CH2Cl2.NH3, which suggests a possible answer of no.

Comment: CH2Cl2 is not nearly as reactive as CH2O - that's why it's used as solvent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the reaction with methanal does not yield your product, DCM, being less reactive, won't as well.

I cannot point out why the reaction stops there, but from Wikipedia it seems that methenamine can be easily converted to a [quaternary ammonium salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternium-15) by simple alkylation.

Furthermore, your product has a problem: if the nitrogens did become quaternary ammonia**, your structure would collapse due to Coulomb repulsion caused by the positive charges.

** I'm not a native speaker, but if equilibrium plural is equilibria, I think it is reasonable for ammonium plural to be ammonia.